# What is the difference between search terms in stackoverflow?

Tags: support, tags, search

I have searched in search bar as "**jqplot**". I have got some few thousand results. when i search as "**[jqplot]**". I have got questions with jqplot tag. What is the difference between these tags?

But when i typed **java** in search bar, it convert it as **[java]** and showed links?

Whats happening these both case?

Answer (score 5):

A quick test would seem to indicate that [the most popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=4&tab=popular) get automatically converted.

So everything through [events](/questions/tagged/events) (#120) get automatically converted from `tagname` to `[tagname]` when you stick them in the search box. If you go past #120 to [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) (#121), a search for `listview` will not be converted to `[listview]`.

If you want to search for a popular tag's name without it converting to a tab, add double-quotes around the term. So to search for `java` instead of `[java]` enter `"java"`:

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) takes you to [java](/questions/tagged/java)
- ["java"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22java%22) takes you to all posts containing the word java

I could be wrong, but it seems to hold.

Comment: So how to search as java? not as [java]

Comment: @PandiyanCool Search: ("Java") with double quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22java%22

Comment: @JoshC okay fine

Comment: @JoshC, I added that to the post.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the confirmation. I can't believe I got it right! I figured there must be something more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Searching for `jqplot` searches for anything containing `jqplot`, while searching for `[jqplot]` searches for questions tagged with [jqplot](/questions/tagged/jqplot).

Java is one of the top tags for the site so it automatically gets converted to the tag search. You can prevent this somehow, but I can't remember or find how right now.